# Oracle regular expression match multiple part of a column value

Tags: regex, oracle

Imagine that I have the below database table with 2 columns

```
row1  AA.B.HOME.CCC.N111.DDDD
row2  RRR.BCD.HOME.CCC.N222.DDDD
row3  AAAA.B.WORK.EEEEE.N111.GGGGG
row4  AA.B.WORK.FFFF.N222.TT
```

I need a query that given "HOME" and "111" in input, need to return only "row1" result.

The number of dots is fixed, but each block can be variable in length.
The "N111" block always start with N.

Is it possible with an Oracle regular expression? How heavy it will be if there are thousand rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like the one below. For 1000 rows, it should perform pretty quickly.

```sql
WITH
    sample_data (col1, col2)
    AS
        (SELECT 'row1', 'AA.B.HOME.CCC.N111.DDDD' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'row2', 'RRR.BCD.HOME.CCC.N222.DDDD' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'row3', 'AAAA.B.WORK.EEEEE.N111.GGGGG' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'row4', 'AA.B.WORK.FFFF.N222.TT' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM sample_data
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col2, '\.HOME\..*\.N111\.');
```

Comment: that's perfect!

Answer (score -1):

```js
const t = `row1  AA.B.HOME.CCC.N111.DDDD
row2  RRR.BCD.HOME.CCC.N222.DDDD
row3  AAAA.B.WORK.EEEEE.N111.GGGGG
row4  AA.B.WORK.FFFF.N222.TT`

const matches = [...t.matchAll(/^(?:[^\.]*\.){2}([^\.]+)\.[^\.]*\.N([^\.]+)\.[^\.]*$/gm)];

// search for the line that has the same name and number as those received as a parameter
const search = (name, num) => {
  const filtred = matches.filter(([_, nameMatch, numMatch]) => name == nameMatch && num == numMatch);
  return filtred.map(x => x[0].match(/^\w+/)[0]);
};

console.log(search("HOME", "111"));
```

Comment: That's javascript and ok, but in that regular expression where I pass my "HOME" and "111" as input ?

Comment: The expression is given, the rest is algorithm. I will modify the code to do this, if you need to.